# Error still shows on chrome console despite being handled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm throwing errors from nodeJs to reactJs

Even though error is handled still I see these errors on chrome console and I do not want them to show.

backend code is like this

```
if([username, password, confirmation_password].some((field)=>field?.trim()==="")){
        statusCode = 400
        statusMessage = 'All fields are required'
}
res.status(statusCode).send({message: statusMessage})
```

front end code is like this

```
.then(()=>{
      navigate("/homepage")

    })
    .catch((Error)=>{
      setText(Error.response['data']['message'])

    })
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, failed requests are logged to the console. Not that it does *not* complain about any sort of unhandled error or rejection. This is just what failed requests look like in the console.

Comment: Once axios.post do not fulfill backend validation, backend throw error to front end and .catch is able to catch that info but still I see errors on chrome console.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: @deceze but I don't want client to see such errors on console. I want them to see only error message part in website where I want to show them.

Comment: Well then you would need to stop _responding_ with such errors. By making your backend respond with a _success_ status code instead, and then send some additional information with the response body, that lets your client-side logic recognize that there was an error, and handle the situation appropriately.

Comment: Even if they weren't logged to the console, any user could still inspect all your requests and responses in the Network tab. It doesn't matter. If someone knows to look at the console at all, there's no point hiding any of this.

Comment: @CBroe but then it will not get caught by .catch statement instead it just navigate it to homepage

Comment: _"but then it will not get caught by .catch statement"_ - no, of course it won't, that's way I said you need to send some _additional_ info then, that allows _you_ to recognize there is an error situation, in your code that handles the "HTTP request was successful" case. Decide for yourself, if _violating_ HTTP just to keep the console clear, is really worth the extra effort :-)

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want see errors,just return statusCode  200 but not any others,then make a judgment in front-end

```js
.then(res => {
  const message = res?.data?.message
  if (message) return setText(message)
  navigate("/homepage")
}
})
```

Comment: Please don't turn HTTP on its head just because you want a "clean console"…